# Is there a better way to add entries from lists to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

As I was studying Python, I came across this task:

> Imagine Python did not have built-in support for sets. Show how we
> could use dictionaries to represent sets. Write the four set
> operations | - ^ & for this new representation of sets.

Below you can see the answer:

> First, for the ‘or’ operation, we add entries to the new dictionary
> from both input lists:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
def t_or(l1,l2):
    result = {}
    for x in l1: result[x] = 0
    for x in l2: result[x] = 0
    print(result)
```

So, I'm wondering why have the author used such a strange method to add entries `result[x] = 0`? Isn't there a better way to do it, maybe using alternatives methods like `.add`, `.insert`, etc?

Comment: Why is that strange?  Dictionaries do not have `add` and `insert` methods.  The way you add entries to a dict is by assigning a value like that.

Comment: BTW, Python did not have sets until Python 2.4, so some of us have actually written code like this.

Comment: @TimRoberts It is strange to me because I didn't expect adding entries by assigning a values. I was like "wait, wait, I add and entry by passing a value to it, I haven't yet even added an entry to pass a value to".

Comment: result = {x:0 for x in l1 + l2}

Comment: @Xdextended. That's how all dictionaries work.  The `[ ]` operator is overloaded to work like array indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result[key] = value` is the way to assign a new pair `key:value` in a Python dictionary. You don't have to create the entry key first on a Dictionary. If you come from Java, for example, the syntaxis is like:

```java
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<int, int>();
result.put(1, 0);
```

As you can see, on Java you are not declaring the key too, the same happens on a lot of languages and that is because of how a dictionary key works.

When you want to retrieve an element from a dictionary, you have to be sure that the key already exists in the dictionary, otherwise it will throw an exception.

The `.add` or `.insert` that you have in mind in Python is `.append` and it is used to add a new element to a list:

```py
my_list = []
my_list.append(0)
```

So no, there is no a better way or a different way to assign new `key:value` pairs on a Python dictionary.